# How to use multiple jQuery Plugins in one File

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, prototypejs, lightbox

I have to use jCarousel and Lightbox plugin both together in a file of php. the jCarousel is working fine for the light box all paths are correct but it always says that

```
 $("#gallery a").lightbox is not a function.
```

Same as for fancy box or how do I can use Lightbox2 of prototype with jQuery.

I used the below for no conflict

```
var $jx = jQuery.noConflict();
$jx(function() {
   $jx(".jgallery").jCarouselLite({
         btnNext: ".morePost",
   visible: 8,
   scroll:8   

 });
```

for using with prototype. The Prototype Light Box Start working but jCarousel does not work after this.

Comment: are you using Jquery and prototype at the same page? is the reference to lightbox script is correct? there are many things to consider. the most probable one is your reference to lightbox script is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use light box as a jquery plug-in or light box2 also as a jquery plug-in.

The light that follow have the steps needed to make it work.

JQuery Light box:

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

JQuery Light box2:

http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/