# How to use multiple jQuery Plugins in one File

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

How to use multiple jQuery Plugins in one File?
I have to use jCarousel and Lightbox plugin both together in a file of php. the jCarousel is working fine for the light box all paths are correct but it always says that

```
$("#gallery a").lightbox is not a function.
```

Same as for fancy box or how do I can use Lightbox2 of prototype with jQuery.

I used the below for no confliction

```
var $jx = jQuery.noConflict();
$jx(function() {
  $jx(".jgallery").jCarouselLite({
     btnNext: ".morePost",
     visible: 8,
     scroll:8   
  });
```

for using with prototype. The Prototype Light Box Start working but jCarousel does not work after this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to minimize/compact plugins into the same js file? Please clarify

Comment: Related: [What do you use to minimize and compress JavaScript libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798315/how-can-i-compact-minimize-pack-my-javascript-closed)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use multiple jQuery Plugins in one File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758438/how-to-use-multiple-jquery-plugins-in-one-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow me to suggest a different alternative here.  If you're including Prototype *just* for the lightgox, don't :)

There's a jQuery version of the lightbox plugin, this will save you the weight on the user's download of 1/2 libraries.  Just use the jQuery version here: http://avioli.github.io/jquery-lightbox/

There are a few variations out there, but no need to include 2 major JavaScript libraries that share similar plugins, just choose one and use the version of plugins that are built on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a compiler to combine all your javascripts in one file. Famous ones are

- [closure by google](http://code.google.com/closure/)
- [yui compresser by yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

Select your poison of choice. There are others you may want to investigate, even open source solutions that you can embed in your projects

Comment: I have to use jcarasoul and Lightbox plugin both together in a file of php. the Jcarasoul is working fine for the light box all paths are correct but it always says that

 $("#gallery a").lightbox is not a funtion. 
Same as for fancy box or how do I can use Lightbox2 of prototype with jQuery.

I used the below for no confliction

var $jx = jQuery.noConflict();
$jx(function() {
   $jx(".jgallery").jCarouselLite({
         btnNext: ".morePost",
   visible: 8,
   scroll:8   

 });
for using with prototype. The Prototype Light Box Start working but Jcarasoul not work after this.